# How to find day-wise maximum value for two years data using pd.Grouper? (Note: TimerGrouper is depreciated)

Tags: python

My data frame has two columns: Timestamp (first column) and Power (second column). On each day, it collects power measurements. Number of samples per day is around 200. Like this I have a two year data. I want to find maximum on each day and I want to plot it.

My code is:

```
one_day_data = df.iloc[:,1].groupby(pd.Grouper(key=df.columns[0],freq='D'))
print(one_day_data.max())
```

Output is:

```
KeyError: 'The grouper name DateTime is not found'
```

Comment: You can achieve the same selecting `max(Power)` grouping by `Timestamp`, after converting `Timestamp` to day. If you provided some rows and the columns of the dataframe an exact solution can be worked out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding hour of daily max using Pandas in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37443296/finding-hour-of-daily-max-using-pandas-in-python)

Comment: its not an exact duplicate but the solutions provided give you a method of obtaining the max power per day over multiple years

Comment: @casualcoder pd.TimeGrouper is depreciated.

Comment: @Msquare yes it has, it now has been replaced by pd.Grouper() which provides an extended functionality. pd.Grouper() can be used in the same manner as pb.TimeGrouper provided you use appropriate parameters

Comment: Do you mean, I can still use TimeGrouper or Do I have to go pd.Grouper(). I did not get it?

Comment: TimeGrouper has been depreciated and should not be used, you now need to use pb.Grouper() instead