# Finding daily maximum and its time-stamp (yyyy:mm:dd hh:mm:ss) in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I actually have a 150 MB data of daily minute-wise measurements for everyday for two years. I have given here a sample data. I want to create a new data frame with maximum of each day with its time-stamp. 
My sample data is:

```
    DateTime            Power
01-Aug-16 10:43:00.000  229.9607961
01-Aug-16 10:43:23.000  230.9030781
01-Aug-16 10:44:00.000  231.716212
01-Aug-16 10:45:00.000  232.4485882
01-Aug-16 10:46:00.000  233.2739154
02-Aug-16 09:42:00.000  229.6851724
02-Aug-16 09:43:00.000  230.9163998
02-Aug-16 09:43:06.000  230.9883337
02-Aug-16 09:44:00.000  231.2569098
02-Aug-16 09:49:00.000  229.5774805
02-Aug-16 09:50:00.000  229.8758693
02-Aug-16 09:51:00.000  229.9825204
03-Aug-16 10:09:00.000  231.3605982
03-Aug-16 10:10:00.000  231.6827163
03-Aug-16 10:11:00.000  231.1580262
03-Aug-16 10:12:00.000  230.4054286
03-Aug-16 10:13:00.000  229.6507959
03-Aug-16 10:13:02.000  229.6268353
03-Aug-16 10:14:00.000  230.4584964
03-Aug-16 10:15:00.000  230.9004206
03-Aug-16 10:16:00.000  231.189036
```

My present code is:

```
max_per_day = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='time',freq='D')).max()
print(max_per_day)
```

My present output is:

```
    time                  
2016-08-01  237.243835
2016-08-02  239.658539
2016-08-03  237.424683
2016-08-04  236.790695
2016-08-05  240.163910
```

Presently it outputs yyyy:mm:dd and value. But I want even hh:mm (or hh:mm:ss) against each maximum value. I tried following code:

```
max_pmpp_day = df.loc[df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).idxmax().iloc[:,0]]
```

The output is:

```
 TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Int64Index'
```

I tried @jezrael answer

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
s = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='DateTime', freq='D'))['Pmpp'].transform('max')
df = df[df['Pmpp'] == s]    
print(df)
```

and output is

```
                     time        Pmpp            DateTime
34    2016-08-01 11:11:00  237.243835 2016-08-01 11:11:00
434   2016-08-02 13:30:02  239.658539 2016-08-02 13:30:02
648   2016-08-03 12:39:00  237.424683 2016-08-03 12:39:00
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) or [`Resampler.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.transform.html) for return `max` values in new `Series` and compare with original column:

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])
s = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='DateTime', freq='D'))['Power'].transform('max')
#alternative
#s = df.resample('D', on='DateTime')['Power'].transform('max')
df = df[df['Power'] == s]
print (df)
              DateTime       Power
4  2016-08-01 10:46:00  233.273915
8  2016-08-02 09:44:00  231.256910
13 2016-08-03 10:10:00  231.682716
```

Or create `DatetimeIndex` and add column after `groupby` for check `idxmax`:

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])
df = df.set_index('DateTime')
df = df.loc[df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D'))['Power'].idxmax()]
print (df)
                          Power
DateTime                       
2016-08-01 10:46:00  233.273915
2016-08-02 09:44:00  231.256910
2016-08-03 10:10:00  231.682716
```

Solution of @Jon Clements, thank you:

```
df = (df.sort_values('Power')
        .groupby(df.DateTime.dt.to_period('D'))
        .last()
        .reset_index(drop=True))
```

Comment: A rather naive approach is to sort and then take the last... `df.sort_values('Power').groupby(df.DateTime.dt.to_period('D')).last()` I bet that's not at all efficient though :p

Comment: @jezrael, Excellent. It worked. I edited my above question. Did you see the latest output? In that, two columns `time`,`DateTime` of same data have appeared. How to eliminate one of them?

Comment: @JonClements - Thank you, also added `.reset_index(drop=True)` for remove `date` index

Comment: @Msquare - I see it - `df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])`, need `df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])` and then `s = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='time', freq='D'))['Pmpp'].transform('max')`

Comment: @jezrael yeah... I deliberately left the index in so if you want to lookup the columns by date you can instead of having to truncate the datetime column again to get it.